# I created a page in wordpress named aboutUs and created a aboutUs.php in the folder that functions.php exist but not showing

Tags: wordpress

The file aboutUs.php is in the same file as page.php and header.php
Here are the steps i took

1. Created page via wordpress and name it About-Us
2. Created a file called aboutUs.php in folder where page.php and header.php exist

These are the steps I took yet any changes made to the aboutUs.php i created does not apply to the page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do it like that: page-{slug}.php, so in your case( if page slug is about-us ) - page-about-us.php
Also check documentation - [Page Template Files](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/)

Comment: So if i want to href it - is this correct -  <li><a class="menu__item" href="/page-about-us.php">About Us</a></li> I changed the page name as well and changes are appearing on page but when i use the href it says page not found (SLUG is correct as well)

Comment: @HadiZouhbi for page href you need write - "/about-us",  like your page slug. "page-" and ".php" is only for file name inside template.